# How to implement custom timing for a SharePoint 2010 Survey?

Tags: 2010, survey-list

How can I implement an Employee Of The Month survey? 
I know how to add a question that will allow one user to select from the All Users List, but how exactly can I make this survey reset itself at the end of the month? 
I am also interestead in implementing a custom timing for this survey, let's say 5 weeks, and not exactly one month.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your survey and save it as a template when you've gotten it how you want it.  Once the survey has run it's course, set the permissions to read only, determine your winner, delete the survey, then create a new one based on the template with the same name.  URLs will continue to work that were previously distributed and it makes relaunching the survey much easier.

Comment: But, how can I make this behaviour automatically? I mean, is there any way I can make this survey close itself, send the results at the end of my predefined period of time, and then relaunch itself?

Comment: You'd probably need a timer job or some sort of scriptd powershell commandlet to fully automate it like that.